# How to get post creation date?

Tags: posts, date

I suppose getting the first revision of a particular post and get the date, right ?

How to do that?

Comment: The `post_date` and `post_date_gmt` is the date the post was created on.

Comment: Thank you Pieter, but it seems both give me last modification date. Are you sure ?

Comment: Then you have a custom filter or function that is modifying your post dates. If a post is modified, that specific date and time is saved as `post_modified`

Comment: I am sorry, but i think this is wrong, at least for scheduled posts : post_date is the scheduled date. And there is no filter i directly query database and get the post then call ->post_date. Any idea to get the very first time the post was added to wordpress ?

Comment: I've just tested it : i retrieve post_date from a scheduled post, it gives me the scheduled date. Not the same for you ?

Comment: I think i found what i needed (although not totally sure at the moment): `get_the_time( $date_format, $new_post );`

Comment: by the way, i was not looking for publishing date, but creation date, the first time a user created the post in wordpress

Comment: Oups, no does not work, it still is the publication date, or scheduled it the post is scheduled.... Strange!

Comment: What have you coded so far yourself? Also, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 10):

The `post_date` and `post_date_gmt` serves as the date that the post was created. For scheduled posts this will be the date on which the post is scheduled to be published.

There is no reliable native method to determine the date when a scheduled post was added. For scheduled posts, you can try the `post_modified` or `post_modified_gmt` dates as this will correspond when the post was first added. You have to remember, this is unreliable as this date will change when a post is modified

Another (unreliable as well) method, is to use revisions. If you have revisions enabled, when a post is scheduled or published, a post revision is saved. That revision, which will be saved after the scheduled post when the scheduled button is clicked, will hold the current post date on which the scheduled button is clicked. Check the pic below

[image]

If you need a reliable way of doing this, you will need to write your own custom function to save the exact time when the scheduled button is clicked to schedule a post

Comment: Thank you, but this is strange there is no such a function

Comment: Is such a function really necessary. Your case is very isolated

Comment: I don't think the case is very isolated, especially now that woocommerce is in the picture and you want to differentiate between the age of products

Comment: @Kirby please explain in an answer

Answer (score 4):

I needed the same info and just figured out by myself. You have to make a custom query to get the first `_wp_old_date` from the `postmeta` table as @dipak_pusti suggested. Run the following statement:

```
global $wpdb;
$post_id = 1234;
$meta_key = '_wp_old_date';
$post_create_date = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
        SELECT MIN($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value) as post_create_date
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = %d
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = %s
    ",
    $post_id,
    $meta_key
) );

if(is_null($post_create_date)) {
    $post_create_date = get_the_date('Y-m-d', $post_id);
}

echo "<p>Post create date is: {$post_create_date}</p>";
```

Note: If the `_wp_old_date` is `NULL` (this means the publish date has never changed) you can use the date from `get_the_date('Y-m-d', $post_id)`.

Comment: I believe this can be simplified by calling `get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_old_date' );`, making sure not to pass a `true` value as the third parameter. The result will be an array of values to check, avoiding the need for an SQL query. As a bonus it uses WP Cache so if you already have a post object no queries are made at all

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_the_date();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) to get the date defined in the meta box "Publish" at the field "Published on ..", this usually is the date the user created the post unless (s)he change it.

Answer (score 1):

When I was stuck with same type of case as yours, i found a meta key `_wp_old_date` with a meta value representing a date.

By Googling this, i found a function is being used to store the old value when a Post or Object is being changed.

https://wpseek.com/function/wp_check_for_changed_dates/

I know, this is very late answer, but it may help others in future. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a query based on the other answers.

```
SELECT p.post_title, 
       (SELECT Min(postmeta.meta_value) 
        FROM   wp_postmeta postmeta 
        WHERE  postmeta.post_id = p.id 
               AND postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_old_date') 
       "First publ from postmeta", 
       DATE(revisions.min_post_modified) 
       "First edit found in revisions", 
       DATE(revisions.min_post_date)                   min_post_date 
FROM   wp_posts p, 
       (SELECT post_parent, 
               Min(pr.post_modified) min_post_modified, 
               Min(pr.post_date)     min_post_date 
        FROM   wp_posts pr 
        GROUP  BY pr.post_parent) revisions 
WHERE  p.id = revisions.post_parent
```