# In which table is saved the original publish date for each post?

Tags: database

I often modify the publish date, but I keep every revision.

Where can I find when the post was published for the first time?

Comment: The publish date only happens once, are you sure it's the publish date and not the post creation/modification dates you're interested in?

Comment: I think the post creation date. When I write a post and I press publish for the first time.

Comment: hmm so if I create a post in January, Publish in February, and modify/update it in March, which would you expect?

Comment: If you've been modifying the publish date, you could look in the `wp_posts` table for posts where the `parent_id` is the ID of the post you're looking at. The first revision is the oldest one WP has saved. But, if you are only saving a limited number of revisions and you've exceeded that, you won't be able to tell the initial publish date because that revision will already have been removed.

Comment: @TomJNowell: I need the creation date. I keep all the revision, but I edit the publish date when I update a post. Can I find the creation date of a post in the wp_posts table, post_date and post_modified fields?

Comment: @WebElaine: can you help me?

Comment: It seems that getting a posts creation date has already been asked, with a pretty comprehensive answer

Comment: Thanks again, I've tried to give a little contribute: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/351648/64590